# Dependencies Not Resolving with Artifactory , SBT 0.13.6, & Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, java-8, sbt, nexus, artifactory

**Update**

If I turn on Anonymous Access in Artifactory then all dependencies are resolved correctly. I am using Artifactory plugin (Generic deployment) and the jenkins user has the read/write permissions on all repositories. Is there anything else that I need to set?

**Problem**
My CI Build Server is Jenkins. I am trying to create an SBT package and resolve the dependencies using local Artifactory repo.

Followed the instructions from here : http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Proxy-Repositories.html

All dependencies resolve correctly if I don't use the local Artifactory repo. But as soon as I try to use the Artifactory repo, I see the following error :

Blockquote 
:: problems summary ::
:::: WARNINGS
        module not found: org.scala-sbt#sbt;0.13.6

```
==== ivy-proxy-releases: tried

  http://repo.local:8081/artifactory/ivy-remote-repo/org.scala-sbt/sbt/0.13.6/ivys/ivy.xml

==== maven-proxy-releases: tried

  http://repo.local:8081/artifactory/libs-release/org/scala-sbt/sbt/0.13.6/sbt-0.13.6.pom

  -- artifact org.scala-sbt#sbt;0.13.6!sbt.jar:

  http://repo.local:8081/artifactory/libs-release/org/scala-sbt/sbt/0.13.6/sbt-0.13.6.jar

==== maven-proxy-snapshots: tried

  http://repo.local:8081/artifactory/libs-snapshot/org/scala-sbt/sbt/0.13.6/sbt-0.13.6.pom

  -- artifact org.scala-sbt#sbt;0.13.6!sbt.jar:

  http://repo.local:8081/artifactory/libs-snapshot/org/scala-sbt/sbt/0.13.6/sbt-0.13.6.jar

    ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

    ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::

    ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

    :: org.scala-sbt#sbt;0.13.6: not found

    ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
```

The /.sbt/repositories file looks like this :

`[repositories]
  ivy-proxy-releases: http://repo.local:8081/artifactory/ivy-remote-repo/, [organization]/[module]/(scala_[scalaVersion]/)(sbt_[sbtVersion]/)[revision]/[type]s/[artifact](-[classifier]).[ext]
  maven-proxy-releases: http://repo.local:8081/artifactory/libs-release/
  maven-proxy-snapshots: http://repo.local:8081/artifactory/libs-snapshot/`

The build.Properties file :

```
template.uuid=30665618-b7de-4174-aeaa-edf647fee712
```

sbt.version=0.13.6

The Shell command in Jenkins is :

```
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin/java -Dsbt.override.build.repos=true -Dsbt.repository.config='.sbt/repositories' -Dsbt.log.noformat=true -jar /opt/sbt-launcher-0.13.6.jar clean clean-files compile dist
```

What am I missing ?

Comment: Does your Artifactory have access correct to the Internet? Can you see the `org.scala-sbt:sbt:0.13.6` dependency in any of the repository Artifactory is hosting?

Comment: I logged onto the server and was able to access https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.scala-sbt/sbt/0.13.6/ivys/ivy.xml .
I can't find  org.scala-sbt:sbt:0.13.6 in Artifactory.

Comment: I'm having the same problem